# How to import An Existing Intel XDK Project in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, cordova, intel-xdk

I am trying to import my existing Intel XDK Project in Android Studio.

Basically what I have is a html5 design with inappbrowser and some other plugins.

I wanted post data to external server using my app like logging in the user.

For that purpose I used HttpUrlConnection in Java Class.

I have working Java I want my Intel XDK Project to embed that class send user inputs to the class and retrieve the result in it.

Comment: You are asking one thing in the title? And describing another in the description

Comment: @OBX My Bad what it should be?

Comment: Are you asking "how do I convert my XDK project into an Android Studio project?" Or are you asking "how do I add Java code to an XDK project?" Your title and post are inconsistent and unclear. One thing that would help to clarify your question: do you want to continue to manage and develop your project in the XDK or do you wish to develop and manage your project in Android Studio?

Answer (score 0):

Because the Intel XDK build system is in the cloud, you cannot see the Android Studio project file (actually, Android SDK command-line project file) that is used to actually build your app.

I recommend that you first convert your app into a Cordova CLI app, which should be sufficient to do what you want to do. If that is not sufficient, then search for how to convert a Cordova app into an Android Studio project.

To convert your Intel XDK project into a Cordova CLI project, see [these basic instructions](https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/intel-xdk/topic/685326#comment-1885369) on the XDK forum and [use this script](https://github.com/xmnboy/xdk-to-cli) to create a proper `config.xml` file from your XDK project settings for use with Cordova CLI.